# how can i use custom filter with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to develop my login process on my app in a secure way. I used spring MVC 3 structure to dispatch the request related urls. My dispatcher servlet handle all request then my login controller maps required pages. I want to add my custom filter for login process (if user already exists, then welcome page appers otherwise an error page).
It may be simple but I am new at spring world. I added my filter into web.xml then it is run. But my question is that how can I trig to my login controller inside of my filter. 
Is there a way of using dispatcher servlet and custom filter at same time, or my mind is just confused.

Please help me,
Best regard

Answer (score 1):

As with most thing in Spring, there are probabaly many ways of doing this.  I like this one: DelegatingFilterProxy.  Search for DelegatingFilterProxy in the [Spring 3.0.x API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/)

In your filter, check if the user is logged in.  If they are not, redirect to your login page.  Otherwise, pass the HttpServletRequest unchanged.

Also, Spring Secuirty is a handy tool for adding security to your web application (not only web).

Answer (score 0):

This topic explains how to use DelegatingFilterProxy:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?20230-Howto-The-joy-that-is-DelegatingFilterProxy